# Google JS API: gapi.auth.signIn callback function issue

Tags: javascript, google-api

When I call gapi.auth.signIn it is called twice: before opening login popup and after user clicks login button. But in both cases `authResponse` parameter is not changed.

Here is my code sample:

```
gapi.auth.signIn({
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
  callback: function(authResponse) {
    console.log(authResponse);
  }
)};
```

And this is how `authResponse` object looks like in both cases

```
{
  client_id: /* my client id */
  cookie_policy: undefined
  error: "immediate_failed"
  error_subtype: "access_denied"
  expires_at: "1422353634"
  expires_in: "86400"
  g_user_cookie_policy: undefined
  issued_at: "1422267234"
  response_type: "token"
  scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
  state: ""
  status: 
       {
         google_logged_in: false
         method: null
         signed_in: false
       }
 }
```

**EDIT:** Before sign in I try to check if user is already authorized in google, here is this code:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: _googleClientId,
      immediate: true,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
    }, function(response) {
      if (response.status.signed_in) {
        connectGoogleSuccess(response);
      } else {
        gapi.auth.signIn({
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
          callback: function(authResponse) {
            console.log(authResponse);
          }
        )};
      }
    }
 );
```

How to make to change authResponse object properly after user clicked 'Login' button?

Any help is appreciated)

Comment: I am stuck with exactly this problem. Any workaround yet?

Comment: @VarunArora, sorry for long feedback, but I've found solution, it is described below, hope it will help you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, here is the workaround I've got.

1. At first, I call `gapi.auth.authorize` method with using parameter `"immediate"=true`, so login popup won't be shown.

   `gapi.auth.authorize({
     client_id: _googleClientId,
     immediate: true,
     scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
   }, function(response) {
     if (response.status.signed_in) {
       connectGoogleSuccess(response);
     } else {
       connectGoogle();
     }
   });`
2. Then I call again `gapi.auth.authorize` method with `"immediate"=true`, so user can input his credentials.

   `connectGoogle() {
     gapi.auth.authorize({
       client_id: _googleClientId,
       immediate: false,
       scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
     }, function(response) {
       if (response.status.signed_in) {
         connectGoogleSuccess(response);
       }
     });
    };`

Hope this will help someone!